# Approximation by Taylor polynomial

Tags: approximation

Let $f(x) = (1 − x)^{-1}$ and $x_{0} = 0.$

(a) Find the nth Taylor polynomial $P_{n}(x)$ for $f(x)$ about $x_{0}$.

(b) Find the smallest value of $n$ necessary for $P_{n}(x)$ to approximate $f(x)$ to
within $10^{-6}$ on $[0; 0.5]$.

For part (a) I get $P_{n}(x)=1+x^{2}+x^{3}+...+x^{n}.$ I don't know how to get started with part (b), is it finding $n$ such that $|f(x)-P_{n}(x)| \leq 10^{-6}$? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could try to use various general expressions for the **remainder**. You may have learned already about the *Lagrange* form of the remainder.

These however often do not give good upper bounds for the error. We want a good upper bound because we were asked to find the *smallest* $n$.

Instead of attempting to use a *general* estimate, we work with our particular function.  Note that the error we make by truncating just after the $x^n$ term is exactly equal to the missing tail, which is
$$x^{n+1}+x^{n+2}+x^{n+3}+\cdots.$$
The sum of this geometric series is equal to
$$\frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x}.$$
In our interval, this is biggest at $x=0.5$, when it is equal to $(0.5)^n$.

So we are trying to find the smallest integer $n$ such that $(0.5)^n\lt 10^{-6}$.

You can solve $(0.5)^t=10^{-6}$ using logarithms. But in this case we can do the problem in our heads, since $1000$ is very close to $2^{10}$.

Comment: Thank you! I was having the exact same problem and this was a huge help!

Answer (score 2):

a is correct.  For part b, you are right you want $|f(x)-P_n(x)|\le 10^{-6}$ over the given interval.  To do that, you need the error term in the Taylor series.  It has the $n+1^{\text{st}}$ derivative in it, you find the maximum of that derivative and plug it in.

Comment: So the problem is now reduced to finding smallest $n$ such that $\left| {\frac{{(k + 1)!{{(1 - \xi )}^{ - (k + 2)}}}}{{(n + 1)!}}{x^{n + 1}}} \right| \le {10^{ - 6}}$ where $x \in [0,0.5]$ and $\zeta $ is between $x$ and $0$. How can it be done?